# PHP environment variables carrying over into child processes

Tags: php, laravel, child-process

I'm having trouble in PHP with environment variables and calling other PHP scripts inside them using functions such as `system()`, `exec()`, and their ilk.  The environment variables from the parent process are getting carried over into child processes.  For example, say I have `foo.php` which contains this:

```
<?php
putenv('FOO=BAR');
system('php ./yap.php');
```

And in the same folder I have `yap.php` which contains this:

```
<?php
echo "Yap sez " . getenv('FOO') . "\n";
```

If I run `php foo.php`, I get this:

```
Yap sez BAR
```

This should not be!  In real life (Laravel), both scripts need to set environment variables to *different* values, but the child process does not see its own values because the ones from the parent process are taking precedence.  How can I avoid this issue and still use the same names for environment variables in both scripts?

Comment: You're demonstrating that yap.php inherits foo.php, but what happens if you set the variable in yap.php? Isn't that the problem you want to solve?

Comment: PHP system call simply fork the current thread, then this new thread make some sort of exec call.
On linux systems, when forking, the child process inherit env vars.
Still On linux systems, exec simply replaces the old executable code by the one from the executed binary. This does not change env vars.

It's an intended behavior that comes down from where and when unix was created.

Comment: @miken32 - Ordinarily that would work, but the issue is more complicated in my case due to how Laravel loads environment variables. When a Laravel (Artisan) script is executed, it apparently won't overwrite environment variables that were already set prior to execution.

Comment: Thanks @Atrakeur for the explanation. It makes sense, but I was not expecting PHP environment variables to leak out of PHP, through the shell, and into another PHP process.  I always assumed they were more constrained in scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preceding the child command with `env -i` does the trick.  So `foo.php` would look like this:

```
<?php
putenv('FOO=BAR');
system('env -i php ./yap.php');
```

This effectively clears the environment variables from the context of the child. The output now looks like:

```
Yap sez
```

For reference, the man page description for the `env -i` flag (on OSX El Capitan anyway) says:

> Execute the utility with only those environment variables specified by name=value options.  The environment inherited by **env** is ignored completely.